# How to iterate over OResultSet from OrientDB in Scala?

Tags: java, scala, orientdb

I'm new to Scala and OrientDb, please help me with this issue.
I'm trying to use OriendDB Java library in my Play Framework Scala project.
This simple code returns the following compiler error:

> value filter is not a member of
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.query.OResultSet[com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocument]

```
val goods: OResultSet[ODocument] = db.query(
  new OSQLSynchQuery[ODocument]("select * from Good"))
for (good: ODocument  <- goods) {
  Logger.debug(good.field( "cost" ))
}
```

The same compiler error I've got if I try:

```
for (good: ODocument  <- db.browseClass("Good")) {
  Logger.debug(good.field( "cost" ))
}
```

How to correctly iterate over this collection in Scala?

Comment: I really doubt you have this message with this code. Plus, it seems to be a compile error, you should mention it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've imported scala.collection.JavaConversions._ and now iterations works

Comment: This is ODB's default answer to scala integration: use asScala, toJava (or the implicit versions of them) . The sucky think about is that it fails is many surprising ways because documents are defined recursively. And good luck passing a scala list or map to ODB (it will certainly fail if your list or map contains scala lists or maps). 

ODB really needs to provide a mapper plugin (e.g. Jackson) -- which fully unmarshalls objects in/out ODB.